# How hard is to implement camera intent and cache?

Tags: android

**Currently learning how to make apps.**

Got an idea but I don't know how to do it or where to look. I was thinking of making a button that opens camera (got that done) and snap a picture, later upload it. I found couple examples how to upload without saving but the quality of image was bad.

What I need:

- Capture image via button and show in imageview (Shows in imageview and uploads)
- Save that picture temporary untill it is uploaded
- Delete that image as soon as it was upload
- Guidance where to look

What I have done:

- Camera intent with ImageView
- Gallery button with ImageView
- Upload button that uses base64

I don't know if camere will work right now because I tested on other project so currenty working on making it work on this project.

```
mCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent photoCaptureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(photoCaptureIntent, request);
        }
    });
```

[Code](https://pastebin.com/CwNp1i7G)

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Code has been added

Comment: Your questions are pretty basic and have been answered a hundred times on stackoverflow and in many tutorials you can find on the web.

Comment: Well I didn't find any that helped me.

Comment: `I found couple examples how to upload without saving but the quality of image was bad.`. As you uploaded only a thumbnail of the image. This has been reported on stackoverflow a hundred times too. Just read some docs to find the very simple solution.

Comment: Could you send a link to it? Because all I found was out dated

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Created a upload method where after picture was uploaded to firebase it will remove the temporary picute that was saved.

This is my upload method:

```
 private void UploadImage() {


    if(filePath != null)
    {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Įkeliama...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/"+ staticSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim()+"_"+ mEditText.getText().toString());
        ref.putFile(filePath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Įkelta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mImageView.setImageResource(0);
                        mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mEditText.setText("");
                        mEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        staticSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCapture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mChoose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        photoFile = new File(String.valueOf(photoFile));
                        photoFile.delete();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Įkelti nepavyko "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mImageView.setImageResource(0);
                        mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mEditText.setText("");
                        mEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        staticSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCapture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mChoose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        photoFile = new File(String.valueOf(photoFile));
                        photoFile.delete();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot
                                .getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Įkelta "+(int)progress+"%");
                    }
                });
    }

    else if(photoFile != null)
    {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Įkeliama...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/"+ staticSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim()+"_"+ mEditText.getText().toString());
        ref.putFile(Uri.fromFile(photoFile))
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Įkelta sėkmingai", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mImageView.setImageResource(0);
                        mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mEditText.setText("");
                        mEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        staticSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCapture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mChoose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        photoFile = new File(String.valueOf(photoFile));
                        photoFile.delete();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Įkelti nepavyko "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mImageView.setImageResource(0);
                        mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mEditText.setText("");
                        mEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        staticSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCapture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mChoose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        photoFile = new File(String.valueOf(photoFile));
                        photoFile.delete();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot
                                .getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Įkelta "+(int)progress+"%");
                    }
                });
    }


}
```